# SO_DEBUG and SO_DONTROUTE in traceroute

Tags: sockets, network-programming, traceroute

Can anyone explain the difference between SO_DEBUG and SO_DONTROUTE . This is my understanding

SO_DONTROUTE

```
            Enable / disable routing bypass for outgoing message

            Routing takes place only when it goes to out of subnet.

            This tell that do not route, directly connect to the destination instead of routing

            SO_DONTROUTE refers to the local routing

            But default it is zero

            Do not route send directly to the connected network

            If the host is not on a directly-attached network
    an error is returned.  This option can be used to ping
    a local host through an interface that has no route.
```

SO_DEBUG

```
            When enabled, the kernel keeps track of detailed
    information about the packets sent and received by TCP for the socket
```

But in traceroute if i give -d option in commandline, SO_DONTROUTE option is also enabled . Also when i enable -r option -d is also enabling . May i know why ?

Comment: What version of traceroute are you using?

Comment: First version of traceroute written by van jacobson

Comment: How did you determine that `-d` turned on `SO_DONTROUTE`?

Comment: I have used strace command to check which options are all enabled

Comment: That's odd. I don't see any reasonable relation between the two flags, and the sources for van jacobson's traceroute make sense - `-r` causes `SO_DONTROUTE` to be set `-d` sets `SO_DEBUG`. Maybe the sources are from a different version. Anyway, this sounds like a bug, not a feature. The (default) traceroute on my Ubuntu 14.04 server doesn't do that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any clear relation between the two flags, so this is (probably) some implementation specific behavior, maybe even a bug.

I've ran `traceroute -d 8.8.8.8` on an Ubuntu 14.04 machine with the default traceroute installed - `Modern traceroute for Linux, version 2.0.20, Aug 19 2014` and managed to reach 8.8.8.8 just fine. With the `-r` flag the traceroute fails with a `Network is unreachable` error message since the machine can't find `8.8.8.8`.

Looking at the `strace` of both `traceroute -r` and `traceroute -d` I've also verified that one calls **only** `setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_DONTROUTE, [1], 4)`, while the other one calls **only** `setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_DEBUG, [1], 4)`.

The sources for Van Jacobson's traceroute from the [official](ftp://ftp.ee.lbl.gov/) (?) should behave in the same way. Here is (a piece) of the code that parses the command line switches:

```
case 'r':
    options |= SO_DONTROUTE;
    break;

case 'd':
    options |= SO_DEBUG;
    break;
```

And here are the socket options:

```
if (options & SO_DEBUG)
    (void)setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_DEBUG, (char *)&on,
        sizeof(on));
if (options & SO_DONTROUTE)
    (void)setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_DONTROUTE, (char *)&on,
        sizeof(on));
```

But perhaps the sources are from a different version..

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. As per your explanation i ran traceroute version 2.0.13, Nov 23 2009 with -d option. And i examine with strace command which only enables SO_DEBUG option. As you told that may be a bug in Van Jacobson's traceroute. Thank you

Comment: Can you please explain me the real world example for both SO_DEBUG and SO_DONTROUTE with any scenario